# Get directories without specific filetype cygwin/bash

Tags: bash, loops, scripting, cygwin

I am trying to organise my music collection's album art, for XBMC etc. and my own personal OCD based reasons.  To do this, I want to loop through each folder in my music collection, (there are also files in `music` hence `$(find . -type d)`.  I check each folder for the existence of a jpeg.  If it exists, it is copied to be called `cover.jpg`.  If no jpeg is found, the name of the folder should be added to a list, which I'll then search google for myself.  The code I'm using is below.

```
#!/bin/bash

IFS=$'\n'

touch missing

cd /cygdrive/d/music

for i in $(find . -type d)
    do cd $i
    if [ -e '*.jpg' ]
    then
        for j in *.jpg
            do cp $j 'cover.jpg'
        done
    else
        cd ..
        $i >> missing
    fi
done
```

## The Problems

1. `cd $i` always fails, as the directory does not exist.
2. `$i >> missing` always fails, with a permission is denied error, however `ls -l missing` gives `-rwxrwxrwx+ 1 Username None 0 Sep 13 16:45 missing`

### Update:

After trying several iterations to get the script to work, I had to give up and simply use this [Album Art Downloader](http://sourceforge.net/projects/album-art/), which in hindsight was the obvious thing to do.  I'm marking the answer with a revised script as accepted as it got me closer to the solution I know is out there, somewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1) cd $i always fails, as the directory does not exist.

since the result of `find . -type -d` is relative to your where you initial working directory, you'll need to cd back to the base directory before doing the next`cd $1`. A quick way to return to the previous directory is `cd -`.

> 2) $i >> missing always fails, with a permission is denied error,

Two problems here. First of all, by doing `$i >> missing` you're actually trying to execute `$i` as a command. If you want the filename appended to the file, you'll need to use `echo $i >> missing`.

Secondly, you created `missing` in your initial working directory, and so you're actually dealing with a different `missing` file once you've `cd`'ed somewhere else. To refer to the same file, use an absolute path.

Try this: (I tried to keep the script as close to what you have as possible and commented on lines that I changed. I've also quoted all paths to better handle filenames with spaces)

```
#!/bin/bash
IFS=$'\n'
MISSING="$(pwd)/missing"  # store absolute path
> "$MISSING". # create new or empty existing

cd /cygdrive/d/music

for i in $(find . -type d)
    do 
    cd "$i"
    if [ -e *.jpg ]  # wildcard not expanded if quoted
    then
        for j in *.jpg
            do cp "$j" 'cover.jpg'
        done
    else
        echo "$i" >> "$MISSING"  # use $MISSING
    fi
    cd -  # go back to previous directory
done
```

p.s. Just in case you haven't noticed, do be aware that if you have more than one `*.jpg` file in a directory, your script will essentially repeatedly overwrite `cover.jpg` with the last one ending up as the actual version. Also, you're likely to see the error "`cp: 'cover.jpg' and 'cover.jpg' are the same file`" if you have more than one jpg file and when `cover.jpg` already exists.

Comment: Thanks for your help so far, I'd forgot to mention in your first answer, `IFS=$'\n'` is needed to loop properly, otherwise it treats all the spaces in the folder names as the next variable

Comment: of course. I just copied the relevant bits. I'll put that in for completeness. Another option would be to use `find . -type d | while read i; do ...` in which case you won't need to change `IFS`.

Answer (score 1):

`cd $i` will fail for a file like "Artist Name - Song Name.mp3". The shell will break it into `Artist` `Name` etc. on whitespace and it will break. You could print `$i` before doing the `cd` to debug the problem.

`$i >> missing` will fail because you're trying to execute `$i` as a script and output the contents into missing. If you want to put the file name, you should use something like `echo "$i" >> missing`.

I recommend you use a real scripting language like Perl or Python rather than do this in shell. Files with spaces in the name are a real pain.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, do you have any recommendations for dealing with the `cd $i` problem, or an alternative script in Perl or Python, if it's not too cheeky to ask for one?  Thanks either way